# Is there a way to have a populated array initially checked as empty, and then incrementally populated

Tags: python

Let's say I have an array that is called expectedList

```
expectedList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

which I will have to compare with another array that is initially empty, and is given a new element every time it loops. I will check to see if they are both arrays are equal to each other during every loop.

Is there a way to have expectedList go through a loop; have it initially as an empty array, and then append an element after a loop. So it would look like this...

```
[]
['a']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I was able to do this in way by having a counter = 0 and i = -1 and increment both when they pass through a for loop. With it not being populated until counter is 1 or greater, like such,

```
results = []
a = ["1", "2", "3"]
i = -1
counter = 0
for j in range(4):
  if (counter >= 1):
    expectedList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    results.extend(expectedList[i])
  #assert of the two lists would be here
  counter += 1
  i += 1
```

This gives me want I want but I was hoping for another, possibly better solution as I don't think mine is the best practice.

Comment: Yeah, you are overthinking this. `for x in a: results.append(x)`

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
results = []
expected = ["a", "b", "c"]
for elem in expected:
  results.extend(elem)
  print(results)
```